# Trigger update and handle null values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I Have a trigger that takes the old values from the orginal tabel and put these values in one cell on another table except the date and user, when any updates occurs, the orginal table has attributes which is null when the raw is inserted like (updatedate and updateuser), so when this raw is updated those two attributes will be update to the current date and user who did the update, so the trigger should get those two parameters when they are null should get the inserted values and when they are not null should get the new values,however the trigger's syntax is correct but the result is incorrect

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[OrdersUpdate] on [dbo].[Orders]
After Update
as
Declare @UpdateDate datetime, @UpdateUser uniqueidentifier
Set @UpdateDate=(Select UpdateDate from deleted)
Set @UpdateUser=(Select UpdateUser from deleted)
If @UpdateDate is null
Begin
Set @UpdateDate=(select UpdateDate from inserted)
End
Else
Set @UpdateDate=(select UpdateDate from deleted)
If @UpdateUser is null
Begin
Set @UpdateUser=(select UpdateUser from inserted)
End
Else
Set @UpdateUser=(select UpdateUser from deleted)
Insert Into UpdateRows
Select 'Orders', id,@UpdateDate,@UpdateUser,
convert(nvarchar,InvoiceID,1)+'_'+
convert(nvarchar,OrderID,1)+'_'+
MatterName+'_'+
convert(nvarchar,PrintID,1)+'_'+
OrderName+'_'+
CONVERT(nvarchar,lenght,1)+'_'+
CONVERT(nvarchar,Wide,1)+'_'+
CONVERT(nvarchar,Quantity,1)+'_'+ 
CONVERT(nvarchar,EnterDate,101)+'_'+ 
CONVERT(nvarchar,EndDate,101)
From deleted
```

Comment: First, you never ever write a sql server trigger where you set the values of a scalar parameter to something from inserted or deleted. These tables can contain multiple rows. The trigger must account for that.

Comment: Thanks for this advise and you're totally right about it, in this case i suppose it's going to return one raw, but if it's not how can i specify one raw, the one who has been updated?

Comment: YOu cannot ever make this supposition, things affect the datbase beyond the user interface. It is irresponsible to write a trigger assiuming only one row  will ever be processed. I'm having trouble seeing what you are actually trying to accomplish, so could you give some sample data from updates and what you woudl expect the trigger to put into Updatearows from that data.

Comment: Thanks A lot, i did solved my problem, but i'll keep you're advise in my mind..... again thanks a lot, but how can i mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

thanks HLGEM

First, you never ever write a sql server trigger where you set the values of a scalar parameter to something from inserted or deleted. These tables can contain multiple rows. The trigger must account for that. –  HLGEM